# Help with a table having fixed number of self-referencing columns

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to design an electronic toll collection system, where I have stumbled on decision how to design **road section**. Each road section is designed in a way that it has references to other road sections that lie ahead(RSA) , behind(RSB) and across(ORS). I tried to visually demonstrate them in figure below.

Visual presentation of Road Section with their primary keys is given below.

```
   |     |    || Road     |
   |          || Section  |
   |     |    || Ahead    |
   |    (1)   ||   (6)    |
------------------------------
   |     |    ||    |     |   
   |          ||          |   
   | Opposite || Road     |    
   | Road     || Section  |
   | Section  ||          |
   |     |    ||    |     |
   |    (2)   ||   (5)    |   
---------|----------|---------
   |          ||          |
   |     |    || Road     |
   |    (3)   || Section  | 
   |     |    || Behind   |
   |     |    ||   (4)    |
```

I have two approaches in mind in designing such entity. The first one is using same table and have 3 columns referencing other rows in the same table.

```
Road Section Table
---------------------------------------------------
| PK_RS | FK_ORS | FK_RSA | FK_RSB | Other data 
---------------------------------------------------
|   5   |   2    |   6    |   4    |  ...
|   4   |   3    |   5    |  null  |  ...
```

The second one is to create separate table for road section relationships, called Road Section Mapping

```
Road Section Table
-----------------------------
| PK_RS | Other data 
-----------------------------
|   4   |  ...
|   5   |  ...
Road Section Map Table
------------------------------------
| PK_RS | FK_ORS | FK_RSA | FK_RSB |
------------------------------------
|   5   |   2    |   6    |   4    |
|   4   |   3    |   5    |  null  |
```

In the first case I will need to create rows with null references at first and update foreign keys later. In second a can create relations after creating road sections first.

What is the best practice in such kind of models?

Comment: May you please add more information to your question, I got confused about the details. thanks

Answer (score -1):

First approach seems to be more logical. 
Because ManyToOne usually stored in same table.